# How to determine ListtBoxItem height inside a scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, listbox, scrollview, listboxitem, stackpanel

I have a listbox inside a Scrollviewer. Listbox doesn't have a scrollviewer(`vertical scroll bar visibility=disabled`), so I can't use `SrollIntoView`. I can only use `Scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset`.

So how to determine ListBoxItemHeight by index? When I can determine the height of listboxItem, then I can use ScrollToVertical offset method.